# Replacing a dll in c++ with conflicting namespaces

Tags: c++, dll

I have a dll in my c++ program and I want to rewrite it myself and replace it out.

The dll I am replacing has 3 classes. I want to replace each class one by one with my new dll, but I do not want to change any of the other code.

To do this I was going to use the same class names in the new dll as in the old one.

However I would like to replace one class, run my program then replace the next class etc so I do not have to try and change everything at once to make sure stuff is working.

Is there a way to do this? I assume if both dlls are included the namespaces will conflict

Comment: Use a typedef instead of the class names directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of what you are trying to do but something such as what Neil indicates might work well enough. It might work to have different namespace names and then just rename the newer namespace to the production name when you are ready to eliminate the old one.

When linking, it is possible to specify multiple lib files. I know that the order of the lib files can determine which is used. I forget if that can be used for this, but perhaps you can specify multiple lib files with the same classes and functions and the linker will use the DLL for the first lib file it finds for the class. I forget the details of how that can work.